# CodeIgniter 3 HMVC ERROR "Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php"

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have a Problem With CodeIgniter 3 HMVC (I use CI 3.1.9 AND php 7.3), When I Create

> MYX3_Controller extends MX_Controller

And i call show_404(); In my Method Will show

ERROR "[Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZkOY.png)"
like this ([Look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4LOh.png)) Why don't show 404 Custom page

Comment: did you load (autoload) the session class?

Comment: since MYX3_Controller extends MX_Controller, I'd just like to make sure that MX_Controller extends CI_Controller (which is the base CI controller)...

Comment: I autoload session class already

Comment: I already setting MX_Controller extends CI_Controller

Answer (score 1):

It usually happen when we use HMVC and we make our own custom error page. I found that we must extents MX_Controller instead of CI_Controller. And the problem should be resolved.

This an example of Cutom404 controller ( location: application/controllers/Custom404.php ) :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Custom404 extends MX_Controller {  // instead of CI_controller

        public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();

        }

      public function index() 
      { 
          $this->load->view('custom_error/custom404'); // change to your own view
      } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because MX_Controller dose not have access of session. i dont know how. if you want to solve it. `MX_Controller extends MY_Controller`

MY_Controller has session class.